# is there a way to make a table that has some td elements with shared borders and some without look normal?

Tags: css, resize, border, html-table

i have a table in a minesweeper browser game im making, in which clicked cells have a "dotted" border, which it then shares with nerby dotted cells. and unclicked ones have a "outset" border, which is not shared. that is exactly what i want, however the problem is the sizing is off as a result, because the sizing of dotted cells varies, and outset cells have a steady size. is it possible to make such a table look normal?

here is my code to help you understand the problem

unclicked box

```
.box{
border: 3px outset #959595;
width:25px;
height: 25px;
}
```

clicked box

```
.zero{
border: 1px dotted #000000;
width:26px;
height: 26px;
}
```

[here is a link if it helps](http://borisute.com/geshem/2013/mkeller/minesweeper.html)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why the clicked cells should be larger than unclicked ones. Cant you just keep the sizes the same? And the border widths?

Comment: @MrLister no it looks bad that way because outset for me looks best at 3px but anyway that isnt the problem as i explained the problem is the shared border making all widths 25 and borders as 1 wouldent help because the dotted share a border

Comment: In that case I'm not sure what to do. Couldn't you make the border color transparent, and give the cells a dotted _outline_? By the way, your program seems to think that the game is a 10×10 grid, but it's 11×11 on the screen. And some of the IDs are the same, for instance the rightmost td of the top row has the same id as the first td in the second row.

Comment: @MrLister tbh i have absolutely no clue what u just wrote

Comment: 1) I meant, instead of making the border dotted, give it a transparent color. Then add the style `outline:1px dotted`.

Comment: @MrLister i tried it it looks very ugly for elements right next to each other